# Difference between prayer times in two mosques of different school of thought

Tags: salat, sunni

Is dhuhr prayer timings are different in Wahabi and sunni muslims? I googled timing of prayers and found in my location dhuhr prayer timing is 12:32 whereas in our nearby masjid it is performed after 1:30. My brother says that it is because we sunni have different timings than wahabi.

Comment: Wahhabism is a **form of Sunni Islam** to restore ''pure monotheistic worship.'' They aren't a different sect to Sunni Islam. Also, If Dhuhr starts at 12:32, you don't have to pray Dhuhr straight away. 1:30 is just the jam'aat and 12:32 is just when the actual salah starts.Everh mosque will not perform Dhuhr at when it starts, but they set a time for jam'aat which would be best suitable for them and the Muslims who want to worship as they might not be able to go to the Mosque because of something like a job etc but are able to go at 1:30.

Comment: so prayer of all the sects ahle hadith, ahle sunni, shia is same but different masjids perform namaz at different times?

Comment: The prayer times for all the Sunni groups are the same with the exception of 'Asr where the Hanafis pray a bit later than the other groups. The Shias I believe generally combine the prayers. Masjids pray at set times, which as the other comment said, is a little after the exact moment when the Salat comes in. Allahu allam.

Comment: @أرمان and AbuMariam please don't post answers in the comment section and try to take your time to elaborate a good answer!